# Adding pagebreaks via VBA doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I created code to set the pagebreaks in an excel report to deal with the orphan issue (i.e. one line of text spills over onto the next page, etc.). The code works fine when I run it with the report open / visible.

It is part of a larger application which is opened and the code executed from MS Access. Excel is not visible during the process to improve performance.

**When I run my code from MS Access it no longer works... it doesn't produce an error, but simply ignores the actual pagebreak setting command.**

I read on various [forums](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=65887) that in order to avoid this problem, excel needs to be first switched over to `ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview`, but that doesn't work either (I suspect since Excel isn't visible).

I have tested for the following:

- Code works when it is started manually or stepped through with F8
- Code is executed when called upon from Access (I set breakpoints)
- Switching the window view doesn't do anything either

**How can I get Excel to change the pagebreaks via code when Excel is run in the background?**

This is my code:

```
Sub TheOrphanProblem()
Dim iPageBrkRow

'Determine if there are page breaks and if so on which row of the document
If FindNthAutoPageBreak(wsRptHolding, 1) Is Nothing Then
    'No pagebreak found so we exit the sub
    Exit Sub
Else
    iPageBrkRow = FindNthAutoPageBreak(wsRptHolding, 1).Row 'Get row
End If

Debug.Print iPageBrkRow

Dim x As Integer
Dim sCase As String
Dim rNewposition As Range
With wsRptHolding
```

'Code edited out for brevity. This part checks if there is an orphan problem and finds the new position for a pagebreak if needed. 
It then provides that position as a range called "rNewposition".

```
'Moves page break to calculated position
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
.HPageBreaks.Add rNewposition
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
End With

End Sub
```

This is the code I use to find the pagebreak positions...

```
Private Function FindNthAutoPageBreak(Sht As Worksheet, Nth As Long) As Range
'Set page break of the last page so that sub asset groups are kept together

Dim HP As HPageBreak
Dim Ctr As Long
For Each HP In Sht.HPageBreaks
    If HP.Type = xlPageBreakAutomatic Then
        Ctr = Ctr + 1
        If Ctr = Nth Then
            Set FindNthAutoPageBreak = HP.Location
        End If
    End If
Next HP

End Function
```

Comment: You're not properly qualifying your objects, which will cause you other issues - it shoudl be: `.Applicaiton.ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview` not just `ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't do the trick. I'm leaving the proper qualifiers in though... thanks.

Comment: Is the page setup of the sheet set to use any of the fit to pages options?

Comment: Yes... in a sub that runs before this one I set the page width to 1 wide using With `.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1`

Comment: That could add additional pagebreaks but it shouldn't remove the ones you have added. Do you turn `PrintCommunication` off?

Comment: I haven't done anything with `PrintCommunication`. Should I simply turn it off, or turn it off and then back on?

Comment: Don't do anything with it. To clarify, are you seeing **additional** pagebreaks, or just not seeing your manual ones?

Comment: I see the automatic pagebreaks, simply not the manual ones which I want to set by code.

Comment: Does it work if you leave out the `FitToPagesWide` part?

Comment: It did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Probably need to see all the code then.

Comment: I don't think I can post the entire code without violating some corporate policy or other... but I appreciate your help thus far. If I find out why this is happening or how to get past the issue, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
```

Comment: I tried your answer and unfortunately the page breaks didn't move. I'm beginning to think this is some kind of nasty excel bug.